# Aggregate on day, month and week level

Tags: tableau-api

I am making a dashboard with clicks on a daily level and a month level on a certain campaign.

If I have say 1 customer clicking on 2 days then at a daily level that customer is counted twice. However, when I look at the aggregate monthly level this person will be counted once.

My SQL code that I am pulling into tableau is at a daily level. How do I get a monthly level view in the dashboard? When I am creating a parameter with month and day..on selecting month it is just adding the day level numbers to give me the month.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a count distinct thing. To get around this the COUNTD would need to happen in Tableau. That would mean you need the Contact ID (or whatever it is you want to count) within the data source. Obviously that would mean your data source is much bigger but is the only way to get an accurate unique count over a custom time period.

Another alternative is to restrict the available time periods for the user and pre-aggregate for those time periods.